# getting a response of recursion(-2) in qunit

Tags: javascript, qunit

I am trying to implement simple link list in javascript, and I am writing unit test cases using qunit.
When I added 2 items to the empty list and tried to test the result using qunit I got this -

[image: image containing the qunit output]

Technically the "prev" should point to the outer object, but I am wondering what exactly is the meaning of recursive(-2).

I am using Firefox 27.0.1.

And how would I go about testing this using qunit.

The qunit code for this output is -

```
deepEqual(linkList.getHead(), {"data": "first", "next": null, "prev": null}, "After adding second data at the end of the list, head of the list retrieved");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to go about testing this sort of situation using qunit (or any unit test js frameqork).

I changed the code to -

```
//creating dummy data
var a = {}, b = {};
a.data = "first"; a.next = b; a.prev = null;
b.data = "second"; b.next = null; b.prev = a;

deepEqual(linkList.getHead(), a, "After adding second data at the end of the list, head of the list retrieved");
```

But I am still skeptical about the exact meaning of recursion(-2). Though, its clear from the above scenario, that the next and prev property will go into an infinite loop.